# initialRoute string is changed, but I end up at the same page regardless the initialRoute string

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

When using shared_preferences on flutter in main.dart in order to change the initialRoute depending on if user have seen the first page or if user is logged in I am getting the boolean which is created throughout the app and added to shared_preferences, every time I start app, I get the initialRoute string correct when debugging, but I still end up getting on the first page, regardless the conditions.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'dart:developer';

import './pages/registration.dart';
import './pages/login_page.dart';
import './pages/confirmation.dart';
import './pages/lang_page.dart';
import './pages/main_page.dart';
import './pages/user_data.dart';
import './provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(CallInfoApp());

class CallInfoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CallInfoAppState createState() => _CallInfoAppState();
}

class _CallInfoAppState extends State<CallInfoApp> {
  SharedPreferences prefs;

  void getSPInstance() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  dynamic langChosen;
  dynamic isLoggedIn;
  String initialRoute;

  void dataGetter() async {
    await getSPInstance();
    setState(() {
      langChosen = prefs.getBool('langChosen');
      // print(langChosen);
      isLoggedIn = prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn');
    });
  }

  void getRoute() async {
    await dataGetter();
    debugger();
    if (langChosen == true && isLoggedIn != true) {
      setState(() {
        initialRoute = '/login_page';
      });
    } else if (isLoggedIn == true) {
      initialRoute = '/main_page';
    } else {
      setState(() {
        initialRoute = '/';
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    debugger();
    getRoute();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);

    return ChangeNotifierProvider<AppData>(
      create: (context) => AppData(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Call-INFO',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        initialRoute: initialRoute,
        routes: {
          '/': (context) => LanguagePage(),
          '/registration_page': (context) => RegistrationPage(),
          '/login_page': (context) => LoginPage(),
          '/confirmation_page': (context) => ConfirmationPage(),
          '/user_data_page': (context) => UserDataPage(),
          '/main_page': (context) => MainPage(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since SharedPreference.getInstance() is an async function it will need some time until the instance is available. If you want to use it for initial route you have to make your main function async and preload it there before your MaterialApp is build.

```
SharedPreference prefs; //make global variable, not best practice
void main() async {
   prefs = await SharedPreference.getInstance();
   runApp(CallInfoApp());
}
```

And remove getSPInstance() from dataGetter

Also keep in midn that prefs.getBool('langChosen') will return null and not false if no entry is made into shared preference so use

```
langChosen = prefs.getBool('langChosen')??false;
isLoggedIn = prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn')??false;
```

While this solution will work it's not really good practice. I would recommend to have the initialRoute fixed to a splash screen and handle forwarding to the right page from there. A simple splash screen could look like that:

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    initSplash();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> initSplash() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final langChosen = prefs.getBool("lang_chosen") ?? false;
    final isLoggedIn = prefs.getBool("logged_in") ?? false;

    if (langChosen == true && isLoggedIn != true) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/login_page');
    } else if (isLoggedIn == true) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/main_page');
    } else {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `initState` to derive the data your logic is based on (i.e. fetching shared pref info). And use `await` keyword so that program will wait until the data is fetched from SharedPrefs. Adding the following code to class _CallInfoAppState should help

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dataGetter();
  }

void dataGetter() async {
    await getSPInstance();
    setState(() {
      langChosen = prefs.getBool('langChosen');
      isLoggedIn = prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn');
    });
  }
```

Comment: this won't work since getRoute will be called before the data is loaded from shared preference and will always set initialroute to "/".

Comment: Since `getRoute()` calls `dataGetter()`, with  `await getSPInstance()` there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I've done that, it doesn't crash on start anymore, but for some reason in getRoute function langChosen and isLoggedIn are null now.

Comment: getRoute() is not an async function, so it won't wait for getSPInstance to finish.

Comment: Now I created a String initialRoute and change it in getRoute() function instead of explicitly returning the value. This allowed me to make getRoute() async and I now await dataGetter(). The only problem now is that I still end up getting to the first page, regardless from the conditions, however initialRoute variable end up being correct when debugging, what can be the problem?

Comment: Cool. Would you please update the code in the original question ? Will take a look first thing tomorrow morning.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to StackOverflow, should I just edit the code in my question, without editing question itself?

Comment: Or should I answer my question and add an updated code?

Comment: If the problem originally posted is solved then you can post it as an answer. However, since the original problem is not yet resolved, please just update the code in the original question (and description, if necessary).

Comment: @Sukhi this won't work. initialRoute will only be used on the first build. Rebuild triggered by setState won't rebuild the app with another initial route.